# init function for structs

Tags: class, go, construct

I realize that Go does not have classes but pushes the idea of structs instead.

Do structs have any sort of initialization function that can be called similar to a __construct() function of a class?

Example:

```
type Console struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func (c *Console) init() {
    c.X = "5"
}

// Here I want my init function to run
var console Console

// or here if I used
var console Console = new(Console)
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Go doesn't have implicit constructors. You would likely write something like this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Console struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

func NewConsole() *Console {
    return &Console{X: 5}
}

var console Console = *NewConsole()

func main() {
    fmt.Println(console)
}
```

Output:

```
{5 0}
```

Comment: This pattern is widely used in golang, but I believe this is not useful for initializing structs embedded in other structs, only for creating new pointers to them. For example, How would I use your `NewConsole()` to initialize Console1 and Console2 inside ConsolePair defined like this?

<code>

type ConsolePair struct {
    Console1, Console2 Console
}
</code>

Answer (score 8):

Go does not have automatic constructors. Typically you create your own `NewT() *T` function which performs the necessary initialization. But it has to be called manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Go struct initialize complete:

```
type Console struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

// Regular use case, create a function for easy create.
func NewConsole(x, y int) *Console {
    return &Console{X: x, Y: y}
}

// "Manually" create the object (Pointer version is same as non '&' version)
consoleP := &Console{X: 1, Y: 2}
console := Console{X: 1, Y: 2}

// Inline init
consoleInline :=  struct {
    X int
    Y int
}{
    X: 1,
    Y: 2,
}
```